# joomla using menu item type alias in multilingual website

Tags: joomla, menu, alias, multilingual

I have a multi language website ( English and arabic) , two menus ( one for arabic and one for english),  I am trying to make the menu item types of arabic menu as alias for the english menu items , The result in front end:
when not using SEO, the arabic meu items are working normally as alias for the english ones , But when turning SEO Enabled , clicking on arabic menu items give 404 Article not found.

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely joomla supported for Multilingual. you can edit to change the menu alias urls.can i know the joomla version you have installed 
Below the very useful to you can you check it now.
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-3-x-configuration-multilanguage-site.html

http://multilingual.demojoomla.com/multi-lingual-tips.html